# Download file from url angular 2

Tags: html, node.js

i have url : `http://localhost:9999/file/bongda.PNG`

i using nodejs serve for public file :

```
application.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

and

```
application.get('/file/:name', function (req, res, next) {

  var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/uploads/',
    dotfiles: 'deny',


    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
  };
    console.log('Express server listening downloads ');
  var fileName = req.params.name;
  res.type('png'); 
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });

});
```

i want to download file from url

i using `<a href="window.location.href='http://localhost:9999/file/bongda.PNG'">123123</a>`
or

```
<a href="http://localhost:9999/file/bongda.PNG">123123</a>
```

but it not success .
please help me ?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: no message throw

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1csrt

Comment: that is image about error

Comment: what is the http-answer for your request to your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="http://localhost:9999/video.mp4" download> Dowload Video </a>
```

i using html5 href .it's OK

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the `javascript:` from the href:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href='http://localhost:9999/file/bongda.PNG'">123123</a>
```

If you'd like to force the browser to download the file instead of opening it, the following line should be added to your backend code:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
```

Comment: :( .no it open link not dowload

Comment: @user3089993, I've extended the answer. You should send one more header.